# Fullcalendar with Rails and looping through inline JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I am getting an unexpected token when trying to populate the events data for fullcalendar. I need a second pair of eyes to tell me what i am doing wrong.
Any help would be appreciated
"Unexpected token <" is what i am getting on the plans.each line but i am ending and starting it in the correct spot.

```
.small-10.columns
    %div
        #calendar

            #wrap
    #external-events
        %h4 Draggable Events
        - @plans.each do |plan|
            .external-event= link_to plan.name, plan
        %p
            %input#drop-remove{type: "checkbox"}/
            %label{for: "drop-remove"} remove after drop
:javascript
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
    left: "prev,next today",
    center: "title",
    right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    defaultView: "month",
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 15,

    events: 
    [
    <% @plans.each do |plan| %>
    {
    title  : "<%= plan.name %>",
    start  : "<%= plan.start_date.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>",
    end    : "<%= plan.end_date.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' %>"
    },
    <% end %>
    ],


    timeFormat: "h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ",
    dragOpacity: "0.5"
        });
    });
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Like i said up above  "Unexpected token <" is what i am getting on the plans.each line but i am ending and starting it in the correct spot.

Comment: Ok well i was using haml so that was the issue because i cant use <% end %> in haml i need to nest in the javascript. I couldnt figure out how to nest correctly to work with haml to i went back to html and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using HAML. Try this:

```
 % @plans.each do |plan|
        {
        title  : = "#{plan.name}" ,
        start  : = "#{plan.start_date.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'}",
        end    : = "#{plan.end_date.strftime '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'"
        },
 % end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this format,

`start: '<%= plan.start_date.to_datetime %>'`

It has worked for me.